# "View more" link for reputation on user profile > summary tab is missing (at times)

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

Jon Skeet has this link on Profile > Summary tab > Reputation section:

<kbd>[image: Jon Skeet Profile]</kbd>

This link keeps on disappearing on my profile:

<kbd>[image: My Profile]</kbd>

I am unable to figure out the criteria behind this. Ideally, the link should be visible at all times for consistency.

Comment: May be it's a _"John Skeet" only_ feature ;-) ...

Comment: I have it on my profile. Now wait a minute, I am suddenly feeling *Jon Skeetishly wisdomous* :P

Comment: I was going to say "it only shows recent changes", but you have much more than 3 unique items recently. I also have the link in my profile, but my last rep change was 3 days ago.

Comment: To get serious, I also see that link on mine ...

Comment: Who is Jon Skeet?

Comment: Hold the phone. Are you surprised that you found ***an***  anomaly in **THE** **Jon Skeet**'s profile?

Comment: @TheBlueDog - Oh my God!!. You will send us back to the *Stone Ages*. [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is  [Jon skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: @TheBlueDog http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts#comment16578_9134

Answer (score 2):

"View more" is only shown unless you have not really a high amount of recent rep events in the shown numbers.

I mean, +15, +15, +15 and +2 have not really rep events associated with them, system considers that it is not enough rep events and show "view more", but +215 has much many in it, so systems considers that you already see lots of recent events and understand that they are only recent.

Comment: I don't think so. I think it is based on the number of posts with event.